# c#, Xamarin.Forms, and SentrySDK context info not making it to sentry errors

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sentry

I am trying to add User & Device context to the SentrySdk using c# and but that information never shows in the sentry portal.

here is the code

```
 SentrySdk.ConfigureScope(scope =>
                {
                    scope.SetTag("SStGAppAId", sstgAppId);
                    scope.User = new User
                    {
                        Id = sstgAppId
                    };
                    scope.Contexts.Device.Model= DeviceInfo.Model;
                    scope.Contexts.Device.Manufacturer = DeviceInfo.Manufacturer;
                    scope.Contexts.Device.Name = DeviceInfo.Name;
                    scope.Contexts.Device.Simulator = DeviceInfo.DeviceType != DeviceType.Physical;                    
                });
```

this what sentry shows
[image]

What is not being done for the context information to be sent to sentry?

Comment: The problem is the flow of the AsyncLocal can be odd on Xamarin. Try to set the datqa in the static constructor of the app (also Init the SDK there). But generally this is something the SDK needs to be improved. There's an issue here: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/628

Answer (score 1):

We solved "Global Mode" on version **3.8.1**.

It makes it so that any call to `SentrySdk.SetTag` or `AddBreadcrumb` or anything else that you do through `SentrySdk.ConfigureScope` mutates a single, static `Scope` object that affects **all threads of the app**. This is useful for Desktop and Mobile apps when you have a single user session and you add context to Sentry anywhere in the app and want that to be included if it crashes in any other thread.

You can opt-in to this mode through:

`options.IsGlobalModeEnabled = true`

This option will be set by default on `Sentry.Xamarin` and `Sentry.Xamarin.Forms` which you could be using to get extra device information and breadcrumbs for system events.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the SDK, a `AsyncLocal` issue. For now to bypass it you can call `SentrySdk.ConfigureScope` every time before logging.